# How to send the uploaded file in mail as an attachment

Tags: php, file-upload, email-attachments

I have uploaded a file using jquery and now i need to send that uploaded file in mail as an attachment.Refer fiddle [file upload](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqxR2/).How to send this upload in mail as an attachment.

HTML

```
  <form id="myform" action="process-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input id="tele" type="file" name="filename"/>
<br/>
<input  class="formbtn" type="submit" value="Upload" />
```

jquery

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        filename: {
            required: true,
            extension: "docx|rtf|doc|pdf"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        filename: {
            required: "Please upload resume",
            extension: "Please upload valid file formats"
        }
    }
});
```

});

php

```
 <?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'from@mail.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Subject';
$email->Body      = 'Message Body';
$email->AddAddress( 'abc@gmail.com' );
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
$email->AddAttachment(basename($target_path . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']));


return $email->Send();
?>
```

Comment: I have not written it yet.My question itself in that only how to send this uploaded file as attachment

Comment: it is not very difficult task.try to google it.visit some links for emails [http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php],[http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php]

Comment: @RamaPriya : Read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail

Comment: refer to this link: http://netsperience.org/content/blog/attach-a-file-email-with-php-code-actually-works

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP Mailer class for that. Check below code for that.

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'from@mail.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Subject';
$email->Body      = 'Message Body';
$email->AddAddress( 'to@mail.com' );

$filetoattach = 'File path';

$email->AddAttachment( $filetoattach , 'filename.doc' );

return $email->Send();
```

You can download php mailer class from this link : [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)

Let me know if you have any query!

Thanks

Comment: i have no idea on how to include php mailer.can you please explain it in a fiddle

Comment: There is nothing like any hard or smart work at all, just download PHPMailer and include class file like this : **require_once('folderpath/class.phpmailer.php');**

Comment: Hi kindly check the updated code.mail function is not working for me

Comment: Why using PHP mail() function? Try with PHPMailer.

Comment: As it is a dynamic function how i need to mention the path for temporary storage and then filename in your code $filetoattach = 'File path';

$email->AddAttachment( $filetoattach , 'filename.doc' );

Comment: Hi now i have updated the code with php mailer function.still its not working.kindly suggest some solution to send attachment in mail.@Chandresh

Comment: are mails going without attachment?

Comment: I think this line: $email->AddAttachment(basename($target_path . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])); should be **$email->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'],basename($target_path . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']));**

Comment: No entire mail functionality is not working simply it remains in same page after chosen the file and click on upload button @urfusion

Comment: $email->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'],basename($target_path . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])); even after changed this line mail functionality is not working @Chandresh

Comment: please check that the object is creating or not
try var_dump($email). if it is working then upload a file on root with a normal mail function

$to      = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From:example@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-Path:noreply@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
//mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-freturn@yourdomain.com')

by this you can check that is your server is able to send mail or not